# Save Method of Application class failed when trying to save an Excel Document

Tags: excel, delphi

I havea a method in Delphi that saves some data into a ExcelFile. The Program works fine for any kind of Excel except Excel 2013.

Here is the code

```
    try
      // If no instance of Word is running, try to Create a new Excel Object
      ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    except
      ShowMessage('Cannot start Excel/Excel not installed ?');
      Exit;
    end;
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts := False;
    ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(xlWBatWorkSheet);
    // fill the Excel file 
    ExcelApp.Visible := True;

    // Save the Workbook
    ExcelApp.save;


    if not VarIsEmpty(ExcelApp) then begin
       ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts := False;  // Discard unsaved files....
       ExcelApp.Quit;
    end;
```

So As I said, this worked fine for Excel untill the 2013 Version. When I try to use this on a computer with Excel 2013 I get the error

```
     Save Method of Application class failed.
```

Any Ideas why is this happening and any possible Workaround?

PS I tried with

```
     ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].SaveAs('c:\test.xlsx', xlWBATWorksheet);
```

I also get an error :

```
SaveAS Method of Workbook class failed.
```

I also read that I could be that I don't have acces to save on that location, but i'm the administrator on the computer.

If I help the time of executing this operation takes a lot more time that It usually did in Excel 2010 or Excel 2007.

Comment: If you have UAC enabled also administrator has normal rights and needs elevation.

Comment: @SirRufo it's set never notify

Comment: Vista and above do not allow you to write to the root of the C: drive. Save your file somewhere else where it belongs, like in the user's Documents folder. (Excel 2013 also works much more strictly with UAC than prior versions did.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn254091(v=office.15).aspx), the Excel `Application` object has no `Save` method. Use `SaveAs` from the `Workbook` object.

You are trying to save a file to the root directory of the system volume, and by default, that is secured so that standard user cannot create files in that location. Even though you are an administrator, UAC means that your process runs with a standard user token.

The other problem I see is that `xlWBATWorksheet` is not a file format constant. You mean to use `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`. This should be fine:

```
Workbook.SaveAs('c:\somedir\test.xlsx', xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
```

where you replace `c:\somedir` with some suitable path on your machine.

Switching to early bound COM might alleviate some of your travails but the answers can always be found in the documentation. You don't need to do this blind.

Comment: I tried with "C:\Users\[current_user]\Documents" and I had the same error.

Comment: Read the second part of the answer please

Comment: [DCC Error] uframeA.pas(1782): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'xlOpenXMLWorkbook'now I have this error.

Comment: Well, clearly that identifier has not been declared. You opted for late bound COM. You need to define all the constants. Websearch/docs has the answer. If you search for that name you'll find its value. IIRC it is 51 but don't take my word for that. And please do locate the documentation. You can't hope for success without that.

Comment: i'm stuck with some other projects right now, that came up from nowhere, I will try tomorrow what you suggested and I will come with an answer :D. Thank you anyways!

Comment: It works, thank you. I also tried with ActiveWorkboox.Save and it also works.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any Microsoft Office automation myself but I do remember from the time that I still used Delphi 7 that when you installed it the installer actually asked you for which version of office do you wanna install the extensions for.

So I would gues that there are some differences in COM implementation that different versions of Microsoft Office use so it is posible that components your Delphi use for Microsoft Office Automation are not compatible with Office 2013.

Comment: He isn't using early bound com. So all that you say does not apply. And even so, new versions of Office support the older type libraries. That is you can use the Excel 2000 type libraries even with Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

May not be relevant but had same error message in VB6 (yes, 2016 and I still use it for odd things on Windows 10!) because the sheet was selected. Selected another object before saving and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install KB2830391 HF460904 for Excel 2013 issue for AX 2009. Change in one sysExcel class on how the transfer/save are made!